# Visual studio web essentials 2013 cannot compile bootstrap.less V3.1.1

Tags: visual-studio, twitter-bootstrap-3, less

I have a fresh ( few days old ) and fully up to date install of VS2103 and Web Essentials 2013.

When I compile a simple less file of my own in "~/Content/bootstrap/less/site.less" it works fine. I Can see the .css files.

But if I try to either import bootstrap in it or compile bootstrap.less itself I get:

```
Compilation Error occurred (see error list to navigate to the error location):
Error found at line 199, column 2:
```

**Question:** Is bootstrap V3.3.1 ( the current one with nuget twitter.bootstrap.less ) using some newest fancy less features that web essentials cannot handle ?

**Note**: Bootstrap.less file does not even have 199 lines and is just a big bunch of import statements. But I cannot get a decent output pointing me to the actually failing file, and hence to the actually failing statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also check https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials2013/issues/1559 which seems possible related to your issue.

According to http://vswebessentials.com/features/less:

> Web Essentials uses the node-less compiler and it always uses the latest version

I did not found or see any issue regarding BS 3.3.1. and the latest version of Less.

Notice that Bootstrap's build process uses grunt-contrib-less v 0.12.0 (released on 23 October 2014) which uses less v1.7.2.

Notice that BS also compiles well with [grunt-contrib-less](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/15463) v 1.0.0 and less 2.2.0

Comment: I'll try to update it all and retry. So far I simply use Koala as a workaround.